# Changing the title of a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

What my program should do, is when you put in a string like "two", instead of a number, a popup will show up saying: You must enter positive numeric data! I have that part down, but I want to change the title on the top of the popup. Right now it just says "Message".

```
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must enter positive numeric data!");
}
```

I need it to look more like this: http://homepages.uc.edu/~thomam/OOProg_1/assignment3.html

By the way, I'm using NetBeans as my IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and you'll see `showMessageDialog` method overloads that take more parameters that will do what you need.

e.g.,

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                 Object message,
                 String title,
                 int messageType)
```

---

If you're going to get one important fact/lesson from this answer, it will be contained in the first 5 words: "Look at the xxx API". Getting very familiar with the Java API will help you **immensely** in your Java studies.

Comment: @camickr JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "You must enter positive numeric data!","Title here!",0); Just giving an example so he could see it in practice.. Because if everyone could just learn from someone copying and pasting the documentation of an API, just imagine.. Oh you dont understand wave and optics power level ? Why here's the formula 
β = 10 log  I  = 20 log  P
I0 P0

Comment: @EduardoDennis: no one is trying to "be a troll", but on the other hand if you're going to give example code, make it sound code. JOptionPane messageTypes should be specified by one of the constant fields that can be found in the API, else there's a risk of using a magic number that makes no sense, and a good risk of confusing someone who is trying to review your code months down the road. Your  initial post had this failing, hence my initial comment. Your edit created code that wouldn't even compile or work, hence my down-vote.